# Do the timeout value in microseconds round off while setting socket timeout

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
    
void print_hex(const char *string)
{
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char *) string;
    int i;
    
    for (i=0; i < strlen(string); ++i) {
        if (! (i % 16) && i)
            printf("\n");
    
        printf("0x%02x ", p[i]);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
    
struct timeval_test{
    long tv_sec;
    long tv_usec;
};

int main()
{
    int sock_ret;
    char ex_recv_timeout[32]={0};
    char des_recv_timeout[32]={1,0};
    int ex_size = sizeof(ex_recv_timeout);
        
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    int ret;
    
    struct timeval_test tv_existing;
    struct timeval_test tv_desired;
    socklen_t existing_len = sizeof(tv_existing);
    socklen_t new_len = sizeof(tv_desired);
    tv_desired.tv_sec=3;
    tv_desired.tv_usec=4010;
        
    if(sockfd == -1)
    {
        printf("Socket not created");
    }
    printf("Sockfd : %d\n",sockfd);
    
    recv(sockfd,ex_recv_timeout,32,0)   ;
    
    sock_ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv_existing, &existing_len);
    printf("sock_ret = %d , &tv_existing.sec = %d, &tv_existing.usec = %d, &existing_len = %d \n",sock_ret,tv_existing.tv_sec,tv_existing.tv_usec,existing_len);    
    
    sock_ret = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv_desired, new_len);
    printf("sock_ret = %d , &new_timeout.sec = %d, &new_timeout.usec = %d, &new_len = %d \n",sock_ret,tv_desired.tv_sec,tv_desired.tv_usec,new_len);
    
    existing_len = sizeof(tv_existing);
    
    sock_ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv_existing, &existing_len);
    printf("sock_ret = %d , &tv_existing.sec = %d, &tv_existing.usec = %d, &existing_len = %d \n",sock_ret,tv_existing.tv_sec,tv_existing.tv_usec,existing_len);
        
    tv_desired.tv_sec=0;
    tv_desired.tv_usec=0;
            
    sock_ret = setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv_desired, new_len);
    printf("sock_ret = %d , &new_timeout.sec = %d, &new_timeout.usec = %d, &new_len = %d \n",sock_ret,tv_desired.tv_sec,tv_desired.tv_usec,new_len);
    
    existing_len = sizeof(tv_existing);
    
    sock_ret = getsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, &tv_existing, &existing_len);
    printf("sock_ret = %d , &tv_existing.sec = %d, &tv_existing.usec = %d, &existing_len = %d \n",sock_ret,tv_existing.tv_sec,tv_existing.tv_usec,existing_len);
    
    return 0;
}
```

The above code creates a socket, sets a timeout and fetches the timeout.
I see that the timeout value in microseconds is rounded off differently on different platforms as shown below ... where 2nd line has value to set and 3rd line is value fetched. Is this difference due to platform or is it machine specific?

```
On Linux 64 it is : 
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 3, &new_timeout.usec = 4010, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 3, &tv_existing.usec = 8000, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 0, &new_timeout.usec = 0, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16

On HP 64 it is 
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 4
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 3, &new_timeout.usec = 4010, &new_len = 8
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 3, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 4
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 0, &new_timeout.usec = 0, &new_len = 8
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 4

On Aix 64 it is :
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 3, &new_timeout.usec = 4010, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 3, &tv_existing.usec = 4010, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 0, &new_timeout.usec = 0, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16

On Power 8 it is : 
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 3, &new_timeout.usec = 4010, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 3, &tv_existing.usec = 10000, &existing_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &new_timeout.sec = 0, &new_timeout.usec = 0, &new_len = 16
sock_ret = 0 , &tv_existing.sec = 0, &tv_existing.usec = 0, &existing_len = 16
```

Comment: Is this compiler-specific? Have you tested with multiple compilers on each system? Do the behaviors differ between the compilers? If not then the `gcc` and `cc` tags are really irrelevant as its dependent on operating system instead.

Comment: Also your program isn't a proper [mcve] as you have code which are used (like the `des_recv_timeout` variable). You also print `"&existing_len"` as message (for example) but the value you print isn't a pointer so the message is misleading. (Yes it's nitpicking but misleading messages or extra unused code just distract from the problem you're trying to describe).

Comment: The `getsockopt`/`setsockop`t are défined in IEEE 1003.1 (POSIX) which states for `SO_RCVTIMEO` that : "_Note that not all implementations allow this option to be set._". I guess that it's the reason why AIX does not set it on an existing socket.

Comment: This time-outs aren't exact values, they cannot be used as an exact timer, a few seconds inaccuracy is perfectly okay, especially if it isn't a real-time system. Perhaps `select(2)` might be a little bit more accurate.